# Using pointers to build a linked list

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some trouble while working with pointers in C. It´s been a long time that I don´t use it so my head is a mess right now.

Function "newstage" creates a stage (just a struct) and it passes for "addintopollingtable". This function will just get the pointers and start to build a linked list.

I'm receiving "assignment from incompatible pointer type" in "(*currentStage)->next=s;" but I don´t know if this is the only problem.

First stage that I build must be pointed by "firstStage", the others must be pointed in "next".

"newstage" will be called many times..

```
stage_t * firstStage = NULL;
stage_t * currentStage = NULL;
int stagesCount = -1;

static void addintopollingtable (stage_t * s) { 
    stagesCount++;

    // First stage
    if (firstStage == NULL)
    {
        firstStage = s;
        currentStage = s;
        return;
    }

    (*currentStage)->next=s;
    currentStage = s;
}

static int newstage() { 
    stage_t * stage=NULL;

    (*stage)=malloc(sizeof(struct lstage_Stage));   
    (*stage)->instances=lstage_lfqueue_new();

    ...

    addintopollingtable(stage);
    return 1;
}
```

My stage_t:

```
typedef struct lstage_Stage * stage_t;

struct lstage_Stage {
   LFqueue_t instances;   
   LFqueue_t event_queue; 
   Pqueue_t ready_queue;  
   pool_t pool;      
   int init_time;     
   int processed;     
   int enabled;       
   char * env;
   size_t env_len;
   volatile unsigned int flags;
   volatile int priority;
   stage_t parent;
   stage_t next;
   int lock;
};
```

Thank you very much! =)

Comment: Don't you think you should tell us the definition of `stage_t`?  Also, a standalone program not using Lua would help.

Comment: I included my stage_t @JohnZwinck =) Thank you!

Comment: Guessing that `(*currentStage)->next` should be `currentStage->next`, but as John said, it's impossible to know without seeing the definition of `stage_t`.

Comment: I received this error including like this @user3386109 "request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union" ..and thanks for your help =)

Comment: Style recommendation: never put a `*` in a typedef. `s` is a pointer to a pointer, but `next` is simply a pointer. First step is to remove the `*` from the typedef, and then explicitly declare which items are to be pointers.

Comment: It looks like you're confused about the semantics of `->`.  You could say `(*currentStage).next=s;`.  That would be fine, but (as K&R say) it's cumbersome and ugly.  The shorthand is `currentStage->next=s;`.

Comment: As the code is currently written, `currentStage` is a `pointer-to-a-pointer`, so he has the syntax correct. The problem is that `next` is a plain old pointer, whereas `s` is a pointer-to-a-pointer. And all of this confusion comes from the `*` in the typedef.

Comment: See [`typedef` pointers — a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/typedef-pointers-a-good-idea/) — succinctly, it is not a good idea.

Comment: There is no way of easing in to this, so I'm not going to bother trying. *Don't bury indirection in typedefs*. There are only two places where it is warranted, and *neither* of those should be attempted until you're **fluent** in C indirection vernacular. (Library authors needing opaque "handle" types and formal callback function specifications are the two exceptions noted). @user3386109 is absolutely correct. Were you forced to spend the extra keystrokes typing those asterisks where needed, problems would have surfaced considerably earlier, and with considerably more *clarity*, before now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is resulted from your typedef

```
 typedef struct lstage_Stage * stage_t;
```

This means stage_t is type which points to struct lstage_Stage.
Therefore, I think the simplest way to correct the error is just declare the variable `stage_t` rather than `stage_t *`. Since they are pointers already.

```
stage_t firstStage = NULL;
stage_t currentStage = NULL;
int stagesCount = -1;

static void addintopollingtable (stage_t s) { 
    stagesCount++;

    // First stage
    if (firstStage == NULL)
    {
        firstStage = s;
        currentStage = s;
        return;
    }

    currentStage->next=s;
    currentStage = s;
}

static int newstage() { 
    stage_t stage=NULL;

    stage=malloc(sizeof(struct lstage_Stage));   
    stage->instances=lstage_lfqueue_new();

    ...

    addintopollingtable(stage);
    return 1;
}
```